# RemoteMavenServer in intellij 13.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea

I cant prevent java process org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer from running which takes 1.8GB memory. Anyone knows what the purpose it has and how to stop it from running? I'm running intellij 13.1.3 on win 7.

Comment: From IDEA community blog, it says It's a process that IDEA uses to work with Maven.

Comment: I got similar problem in idea-IC-173.4301.25. java process org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer takes more than 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped running org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer by going to "Settings/Plugins" and uncheck "Maven Integration". My IDEA version is 2017.3.